# Trigger email alerts to a group of people when quotas limits are reached

Tags: 2007, quota

I need your advice with the following: I would like to trigger an email alert to a group of people when one of the quotas limits “StorageWarningLevel” or “StorageMaximumLevel” are reached.

By default an email is only sent to the site collection admin(s) when the limit is reached, but I would also like to send emails to other people, not only site collection admins.

How would you implement this? Is it possible to develop a SharePoint feature that periodically checks the these quotas and sends the emails? Or is there an easier/better way to accomplish this within SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own timer job that calculates the total file usage for the site collection and compares to the siteCollection.Quota.StorageWarningLevel and sends the emails.

A much simpler solution would be for the site collection admin to create a rule in Outlook to auto-forward all messages with the subject of your quota email.

Comment: thanks a lot Laurie, i will try using a feature that implements a timer job !

Answer (score 1):

I havent tried this, and dont have access to a farm right now, but a smple solution would be to add a distribution list as email instead of a specific user?

Comment: I believe I've tried this in the past, the site owners must be people.  I seem to recall it will yell at you if you use an email enabled security group.